# Page breaks in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

[image]I have tried to create pages using array of objects, As of now i am able to break the pages using the below code.
My array will be like this

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "abc",
   "checked":true
  },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "content": "xyz",
   "checked":true
  },
   {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "xyz",
   "checked":true
  },
   {
    "id": 4,
    "content": "xyz"
  }
]
```

Creating pages from below code

```
 createPageNos() {
        var newPageContentLength = 0;
        var pageNo = 1;
        var pageObj = {
          page: `page${pageNo}`,
          data: []
        };
        let temp = [];

        this.contentArray.map(function (item) {
          if (item.checked) {
            temp.push(item);
          }
        })

        this.contentViewArray = [];
        temp.forEach((item, i) => {
            newPageContentLength += item.content.length;
          if (i == 0) {
              pageObj.data.push({ ...item, ischecked: true });
            } else {
            if (newPageContentLength < 5000) {
                pageObj.data.push({ ...item, ischecked: true });
              } else {
                  this.contentViewArray.push({ ...pageObj });
                pageNo += 1;
                pageObj = {
                  page: `page${pageNo}`,
                  data: [{ ...item, ischecked: true }]
                };
                newPageContentLength = item.content.length;
              }
            }
          if (i == temp.length - 1) {
                this.contentViewArray.push({ ...pageObj });
            }

        });

      }
```

Link for Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jelfzk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Page limit is 5000 characters per page
From the above code if 3 objects having 3000 and 1000 and 3000 characters, First and second object is going to first page and third object of 3000 characters completely to second page.
3rd object 1000 characters has to go to page 1 and other 2000 characters to second page.This is not happening can anyone help me on this issue

Comment: Unable to get the logic behind page break>

Comment: Can you please share the editor url of your stackblitz for forking purposes?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jelfzk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @PrashantPimpale added screenshot

Comment: Add proper explaination about the logic:) Unable to understand: `Page limit is 5000 characters per page From the above code if 3 objects having 3000 and 1000 and 3000 characters, First and second object is going to first page and third object of 3000 characters completely to second page. 3rd object 1000 characters has to go to page 1 and other 2000 characters to second page.`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale per page it has to fit 5000 characters, from 5001 characters to 10000 it has to fit in second page :) , Any help will be great

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm any solution plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to code the split of your third object.

I'm not sure to understand you, i understand from your example you want to do something like that :

```
[
    {
      id: 1,
      content: "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      content: "xyz"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      content: "xyz"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      content: "xyz"
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      content: "xyz"
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      content: "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc"
    }
  ];
```

Become pages of 20 caracteres like that :

```
[
  {
    "page": "page1",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "content": "abcabcabcabcabcabcab",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": "page2",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "content": "cabcabcabcabcabcabca",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": "page3",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "content": "bcabc",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "content": "xyz",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "content": "xyz",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "content": "xyz",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "content": "xyz",
        "checked": true
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "content": "abc",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": "page4",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "content": "abcabcabcabcabcabcab",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": "page5",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "content": "cabcabcabcabcabcabca",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": "page6",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "content": "bc",
        "checked": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I used a recursive function for the fun :) Try this into your stackBlitz example.

```
private NB_BY_PAGE = 20;
  viewArray = [];
  constructor() {
    var newPageContentLength = 0;
    var pageNo = 1;
    var pageObj = {
      page: `page${pageNo}`,
      data: []
    };

    this.originalArray.forEach((item, i) => {
        [pageObj, newPageContentLength, pageNo] = this.cutInPages(item, pageObj, newPageContentLength, pageNo);
      if (i == this.originalArray.length - 1) {
        this.viewArray.push({ ...pageObj });
      }
    });
  }

  private cutInPages(item, pageObj, newPageContentLength, pageNo) {
      let numberNeededToCompleteCurrentPage = this.NB_BY_PAGE - newPageContentLength;
        if (item.content.length <= numberNeededToCompleteCurrentPage) {
          pageObj.data.push({ ...item, checked: true });
          newPageContentLength += item.content.length;
          return [pageObj, newPageContentLength, pageNo]
        } else {
          let firstPartItem = {id:item.id, content: item.content.substr(0, numberNeededToCompleteCurrentPage), checked: true};
          pageObj.data.push({ ...firstPartItem, checked: true });
          this.viewArray.push({ ...pageObj });
          pageNo += 1;
          pageObj = {
            page: `page${pageNo}`,
            data: []
          };
          newPageContentLength = 0
          let secundPartItem = {id:item.id,
              content: item.content.substr(numberNeededToCompleteCurrentPage, item.content.length), checked: true};
              return this.cutInPages(secundPartItem, pageObj, newPageContentLength, pageNo);
        }
  }
```

Comment: can u please add stackblitz link

Comment: Got solution added your code and working as ecpected  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eabpvd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Perfect. Good luck.